# Why does the author use ContinueWith() and async methods variants when it seems pointless

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task

I've been reading Essential C# 6.0 recently. In the chapter of the book where author explains multi threading he shows this method and I don't understand two things about it which don't seem to be explained anywhere.

```
private static Task WriteWebRequestSizeAsync(string url)
{
    StreamReader reader = null;
    WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);

    Task task = webRequest.GetResponseAsync()
        .ContinueWith(antecedent =>
        {
            WebResponse response = antecedent.Result;
            reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            return reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        })
        .Unwrap()
        .ContinueWith(antecedent =>
        {
            if(reader != null) reader.Dispose();
            string text = antecedent.Result;
            Console.WriteLine(text.Length);
        });
    return task;
}
```

**1.** Why does the author use `ContinueWith()` methods and calls them **essential**? How is his way of doing it better than my approach, which does not utilize these methods?

```
private static Task WriteWebRequestSizeAsync(string url)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
        WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponseAsync().Result;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string text = reader.ReadToEndAsync().Result;
            Console.WriteLine(text.Length);
        }
    });
}
```

**2.** Why does the author use **async** variants of the methods and then access their result via `.Result` property, instead of using **not async** variants as it appears to have the same result at the end. **Please, notice that I haven't changed it in my approach above**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you are calling GetResponseAsync() in your method, however, trying to use `.Result` makes it a blocking call.As a result of this your task continues to wait for the result to be available wasting cpu cycles.

```
WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponseAsync().Result; //blocking call
```

However, in the example by author, GetResponseAsync() is followed by a ContinueWith(). This means that Task on which GetResponseAsync() is called won't be blocked and can be utilized to do something else. When the result of GetResponseAsync() is available the continuation will run.

```
 webRequest.GetResponseAsync()
        .ContinueWith(antecedent =>
        {
            WebResponse response = antecedent.Result;
            reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            return reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        })
```

Same example can also be written using async and await instead of continuation...This will have a similar effect of continuations . However, this will be more natural to read.

```
var result = await webRequest.GetResponseAsync();
//do something with result now.
```

Comment: Thanks! It cleared this up a lot for me, but what if I used sync methods in my approach? Would it also block, wasting CPU cycles?

Comment: Yes...Whatever thread it will run on it will be blocked. The idea is if there is an I/O bound operation i.e. you are trying to do some operation such as reading from file, calling a web service, call to database etc. where the actual work is done by someone else such as database server and your thread is just waiting for result to be available , you would like to do them in an async manner so that until the result is being made available to you , your Task can be returned to the pool and can be used to do something else.

Answer (score -1):

It seems as if the author uses stacked continuation in order to split the operations according to the seperation of concerns principle.

Answer (score -1):

Main difference between yours and authors way is that author runs code in the same thread from what method `WriteWebRequestSizeAsync` while your code will run in some thread from ThreadPull. 
I don't know context so may be it's essential.
About second question. If author calls *not async*  methods he could not get tasks and attach to them `ContinueWith`.